# Notifications under Azure Redis cache

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

I am currently working on Azure Redis cache. Under notification, I didnt see any field to add group for notification?
How to add notification to specific emails under Azure cache?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create alerts in Azure Redis Cache for notification. After creating alerts, we need to create action groups and provide email ids where we need to send email notifications.

[image]

You can get more details on below articles:

[How to monitor Azure Redis Cache](https://github.com/rgl/azure-content/blob/master/articles/redis-cache/cache-how-to-monitor.md)

[Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-monitor#operations-and-alerts)